# How to pass a class/object through constructor in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I want to make a wrapper `Filer` class to work with `fstream` library.

Thus, I want to pass an instance of `fstream` class through constructor of my own Filer class, which led to this code:

```
Filer::Filer(fstream fileObject)
{
    fileObject this->fileObj;
};
```

Though when I compile it, an error is thrown that :

```
1>Filer.cpp(10): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'this'
```

While when I do this:

```
Filer::Filer(fstream fileObject)
{
    this->fileObj = fileObject;
};
```

It throws this errors which complains that fstream could not be assigned in such way;

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::fstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

How should I then make my constructor accept an object of type `fstream`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've got there is not C++.  Try this:

```
Filer::Filer(fstream& fileObject)
  : fileObj(fileObject)
{
}
```

That uses an "initialization list" to store a reference to `fileObject` which must be declared as a member of the class.  And you must use references, because streams are not copyable.

Comment: Well, can I ask you when in the header file we are specifying the class, what type should be assigned to `fileObj` ? I mean how should we declare `fileObj` ? `string fileObj;` actually does not work

Comment: @MostafaTalebi of course it doesn't work, `fstream` is not a `string` and `string` is not a `fstream`. Declare `fileObj` as a reference to a `fstream` - `std::fstream& fileObj`.